# Create a Team Calendar using SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have created a group calendar in SharePoint 2010. Everything went very well except the events show up in the All Items list view, but I cannot figure out how to get them to appear on the calendar.

When I add a new item on the calendar , none of the new events created on this calendar are appearing on the actual calendar. If, however, I change the view to "All Events", it will show my created events.

It might have something to do with the Group Calendar Options. I made a test by  creating another Calendar and I added some events. I can see them in the calendar but if I go to the list setting and change the option for Group Calendar Options all the events has gone.

I was wondering how can I make it works? thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the calendar and looking on the left side under the small calendar for "calendars in view"  See if there are more to add in there.

Comment: hi Jammin4CO you've just saved my entire life. Thank you a lot for that.

Answer (score 0):

that was the answer from Jammin4CO

Try viewing the calendar and looking on the left side under the small calendar for "calendars in view" See if there are more to add in there.